# Incorrect axis labels with scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a ggplot boxplot using `facet_wrap` to show two sites. My x axis has three possible treatments, control, bagged, or scattered. In order to remove an empty column in the `facet_wrap`, I have used `facet_wrap(~site, scales = "free_x")`, as each site contains a control and either bagged or scattered. I also want to change my axis labels from 'A_Control' to 'Control' etc, so have used `scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Control','Bagged','Scattered'))`. However, my problem is when I use the below code to plot it, it removes the label for scattered and replaces it with bagged for site B, and I'm struggling to work out where the problem is. I have included the incorrect plot at the bottom.

```
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", color="red")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Control','Bagged','Scattered'))+
  facet_wrap(~site, scales = "free_x")
```

My data:

````
  salmon_biomass = c(0.263678451,0.721658206,
                     0.214856902,0.267343486,0.250631313,0.105008418,2.645833333,
                     1.702020202),
            site = as.factor(c("Site A",
                               "Site A","Site A","Site A","Site B","Site B",
                               "Site B","Site B")),
         section = as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B")),
       treatment = as.factor(c("A_Control",
                               "B_Bagged","A_Control","B_Bagged","A_Control",
                               "C_Scattered","A_Control","C_Scattered"))```
````

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a named vector for the `labels` in `scale_x_discrete` :

```r
  ggplot(df, aes(treatment, salmon_biomass)) +
    geom_boxplot()+
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", color="red")+
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c(B_Bagged = "Bagged", 
                                A_Control = 'Control',
                                C_Scattered = 'Scattered')) +
    facet_wrap(~site, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was so simple